# Get the roots of a system with constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I have the following system of equation

```
A = np.diag((-2, -1, 0, 1))
x = np.array([0, 1, 1, 1])

Lambda, U = np.linalg.eig(A)
f1 = lambda l, r: 1. / np.linalg.norm(np.dot(U.T @ np.diag(1. / (Lambda + r*l)) @ U, x)) - 1. / l
f2 = lambda l, r: 1. / np.linalg.norm(np.dot(U.T @ np.diag(1. / (Lambda + r*l)) @ U, x)) - 1

def equations(p):
    xx, yy = p
    return f1(xx, yy), f2(xx, yy)
```

and I want to compute the roots. I the system was without constants I could have used

```
initial_guess = np.array([4, 3])
res_root = root(equations, initial_guess, method='lm')
print('res_root {}'.format(res_root.x))
```

However, the roots must me non negative and the their product should me bigger than zero or the minus the smallest value in `A`. In this case the product should be bigger that 2. Is there a way to impose these constraints?

Comment: Can you make some comments on what's the purpose of your *alternating scheme*? Note also fun1's and fun2's jacobian isn't correct since the first/second component of the equation system is zero.

Comment: @joni thanks for the interest, I gave the exact context I am working. What bothers me is the product constraint and I was thinking If it was more preferable to solve the system by solving each equation separately and then use the updated values to solve them again. The example I gave before my edit was to verify my thought If the `alternating` scheme is possible. Any help is highly appreciated.